# opengles drawing color changing with xcode 9

Tags: ios, opengl-es

My app uses OpenGL ES for rendering a screen where the user draws his signature. 
My code has been working fine for over 3 years, but after upgrading to Xcode 9 I am getting a strange color change in the lines I draw (both on the simulator and the device). 
The lines used to have a pure red, green, or blue color, and now they have a grey/black line mixed in.
I do not know much about OpenGL and my code was put together from sample apps and tutorials.

What might have caused this change?

This is the drawing after upgrading to Xcode 9:
[image: drawing after upgrading xcode]

The code to change color:

```
// Change the brush color
- (void)changeBrushColor:(NSString *) newColor
{
    SEL setcolor = NSSelectorFromString(newColor);
    UIColor *nColor =  [UIColor performSelector:setcolor];

    CGColorRef color = nColor.CGColor;
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color);

    brushColor[0] = (GLfloat) components[0];
    brushColor[1] =  (GLfloat) components[1];
    brushColor[2] =  (GLfloat) components[2];
    brushColor[3] =  (GLfloat) components[3];

    if (initialized) {
        glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);
        glUniform4fv(program[PROGRAM_POINT].uniform[UNIFORM_VERTEX_COLOR], 1, brushColor);
    }
}
```

The code to draw:
     CGPoint newMidPoint = CGPointMake(x/scale, y/scale);

```
    [currentStroke insertObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newMidPoint] atIndex:2];
    [currentStroke removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [currentStroke removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@" after draw currentstroke %@: ", currentStroke);


    // Load data to the Vertex Buffer Object & Draw it
    //glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // Draw
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (int)vertexCount);

    // Display the buffer
    //glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

init code:

```
       - (BOOL)initGL
        {
            // Generate IDs for a framebuffer object and a color renderbuffer
            glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
            g

    lGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);
            glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
            // This cal

l associates the storage for the current render buffer with the EAGLDrawable (our CAEAGLLayer)
        // allowing us to draw into a buffer that will later be rendered to screen wherever the layer is (which corresponds with our view).
        [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);


        if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        {
            NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
            return NO;
        }

        // Setup the view port in Pixels
        glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

        // Create a Vertex Buffer Object to hold our data
        glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);

        // Load the brush texture
        brushTexture = [self textureFromName:@"brush"];

        // Load shaders
        [self setupShaders];

        // Enable blending and set a blending function appropriate for premultiplied alpha pixel data
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        //moved from draw
        glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);

    //    //***** for testing ******
    //    [self sample];
    //    //***** for testing ******

        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem. I used a brush texture image that was 64x64 versus 32x32 and that resolved the issue. I am not sure why this worked and would still like some comments on what caused the problem.